# Use function that accepts io.Writer as HandleFunc

Tags: go, lambda, interface, type-assertion

I would like to make a function that can be a HandleFunc for `http` but also be called with another writer.

Since `http.ResponseWriter` implements `io.Writer` and my function does not need to set HTTP headers, I thought it might be possible:

```
func doit(w io.Writer, r *http.Request) {
  w.Write([]byte("Hello"))
}

http.HandleFunc("/", doit)
```

But no:

> cannot use doit (type func(io.Writer, *http.Request)) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to http.HandleFunc

That makes sense, because it would require a type assertion to make an io.Writer compatible with an expected http.ResponseWriter.

Is something like that possible with functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Spec: Function types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_types)

> A function type denotes the set of all functions with the same parameter and result types.

Your `doit()` function does not qualify to be an [`http.HandlerFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) because parameter types do not match. The types [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) and [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) are 2 completely different types, so the function types taking these types are also different.

#### Using an anonymous function value

However, since the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of the interface type `io.Writer` is a subset of the method set of `http.ResponseWriter`, a value of the latter type can be [assigned](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the variable of the former type.

You may wrap it in an anonymous function of type `http.HandlerFunc` which may simply call `doit()`, and then you may use it as an `http.HandlerFunc`:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    doit(w, r)
})
```

#### Anonymous function value with helper function

If you need this many times, you may create a helper function to produce the `http.HandlerFunc` function value:

```
func wrap(f func(w io.Writer, r *http.Request)) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        f(w, r)
    }
}
```

And then using it is simply:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", wrap(doit))
```

#### With custom `Handler` type

Another option would be to define your own function type, to which you can attach a simple method to implement [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) (namely `ServeHTTP()`), and that way with a simple type [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) you can register your function as a handler:

```
type SimpleHandler func(io.Writer, *http.Request)

func (sh SimpleHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    sh(w, r)
}
```

Using it:

```
http.Handle("/", SimpleHandler(doit))
```

Note that the expression `SimpleHandler(doit)` is simply a type conversion, it's not a function call. So there are no new values or anonymous functions created here in the background, this solution is the most efficient.